# О состояниях опьянения

Tags: фразеология

Можно (но не нужно))) напиться в стельку, в дрова, в хлам. Это все понятно - до состояния, когда человек может только лежать. А вот что значит "напиться в дым"?

Comment: Напиться "в дрызг", "до белых риз", "до зелёного змия", "до невменяемости", "до стекольного звона", "в дымину" (так слышал). Русский язык богат подобными лингвистическими открытиями, ещё Н. В. Гоголь отметил эту особенность русского человека - одним словцом сказать всё сразу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, потому что глаза не видят - всё как в дыму,в тумане, неясно и колеблется?

А может, соотносительно с поговоркой "дым коромыслом" - весёлая безудержная гульба. Значит, не до беспамятства, а только до безудержного веселья.